# Can't Adjust Brightness In ASUS X401U

Tags: 14.04, ati, brightness, asus

i have a problem with my Ubuntu 14.04. I installed it on my ASUS X401U and i can't adjust the screen brightness trough the Fn. key or system setting.
i have tried some way like edit the grub file. but it doesn't work. it just make the brightness low but still unchangeable. I found another way but they just talk about Intel user. I'm using AMD for all chipset including graphics.
could you help me to fix this and make Ubuntu better?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

1. Edit /etc/default/grub
2. edit line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
3. Save
4. In terminal "sudo update-grub"
5. reboot

This work for my X401u (AMD c-60,Radeon 6290) with Ubuntu-mate 15.10